# Update/delete on table that does not use AcidOutputFormat or not bucketed

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have updated the hive-site.xml file with below properties:

```
set hive.support.concurrency = true; 
set hive.enforce.bucketing = true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;
set hive.txn.manager = org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager;
set hive.compactor.initiator.on = true;
set hive.compactor.worker.threads = 1;
```

I am trying to update a table with below command:

```
update employee_basic set dept = 'IT';
```

but getting error:

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10297]: Attempt to do update or
>   delete on table employee_det.employee_basic that does not use an
>   AcidOutputFormat or is not bucketed

Comment: And your table storage format is?

Comment: row format table

Comment: Stored as ... ?

Answer (score 3):

From given details, look like you have enabled Hive `ACID`.

For `ACID` support table need to be in `ORC` format and bucket enabled.

I see you have enabled bucket but not sure if table is in `ORC` format. Check table definition using `show create table` , to know if it satisfies above conditions.

See more details at 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions

Answer (score 0):

> "Only ORC file format is supported in this first release.  The feature
>   has been built such that transactions can be used by any storage
>   format that can determine how updates or deletes apply to base records
>   (basically, that has an explicit or implicit row id), but so far the
>   integration work has only been done for ORC."
>
> https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions